# Need Zoom reset after uploading new image and remove old image zoom is not getting reset for uploading a new image

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mestorf-wihi8 Hi in this code when i upload an image adjust the zoom for first image and save it & if i remove the old image and upload the new one the zoom is not getting reset how to reset the zoom for uploading any new image.

Below is the zoomslider code:

```
         function handleZoomSlider(event, value) {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, zoom: value }));
      }
```

Comment: try setting `setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, zoom:1,  img: url, cropperOpen: true }));` inside **handleFileChange** function so that whenever file changes zoom is set to default i.e. 1 in this case.